# how to divide students in sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, loops, mysqli

I want to divide student group-wise and store them in database

```
students 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15.....20
```

**Example:** `Total no.of students 20`

Make 4 students per group (1,2,3,4 group1 and 5,6,7,8 group2 etc.....)

Then there should 5 groups created

i tried like this where the mistake i am doing in for loops.

```
$studentQuery = $conn->query("
select s.student_pid,i.email,s.student_email,s.student_fname,
s.student_lname,s.profile_pic from r_job_invitations i 
LEFT JOIN 
tbl_students s 
ON 
i.email = s.student_email 
where i.id_job = ".$jobID." and inv_res = 1");

$totalIndividuals    = mysqli_num_rows($studentQuery);
$groups = round($totalIndividuals/5,0,PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
   for ($j = 1; $j <= $groups; $j++) {
        for ($i = 0; $i <= $totalIndividuals; $i++) {
            $GroupsQuery = $conn->query("INSERT INTO 
                r_test_group (student_id,job_id,group_name) 
                values ('".$studentResults['student_pid']."',
                           '".$jobID."','Group'".$j." )");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$stuData = array();
while($studentResults = $studentQuery->fetch_array())   {
    $stuData[] = $studentResults;
}
$totalIndividuals    = mysqli_num_rows($studentQuery);
$groups = round($totalIndividuals/$gd_individuals,0,PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
$count=0;
for($j = 0; $j<$groups; $j++)   {
    for($i =0; $i< $gd_individuals; $i++)   {
        if($stuData[$count]['student_pid']) {
            echo "INSERT INTO r_test_group (student_id,job_id,group_name) values (".$stuData[$count]['student_pid'].", ".$jobID.",Group".$j." )";
            $count++;
        }
    }
}
exit;
```

first forloop is to divide groups.
Second forloop is to divide for students.

Answer (score 1):

Considering there is no gaps between the records

```
select Concat('group',(your_col - 1 ) / 4 +  1 )
From yourtable
```

**Note :** This will **not** work when there is gaps. If you have gaps then you need to generate row number for each row then replace then `student_id` with row number in my query.

Comment: There are *always* gaps

Comment: @YourCommonSense - well at least not present in OP's example ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could use flooring to translate a student id to a group id:

```
INSERT INTO r_test_group 
(student_id,job_id,group_name) 
SELECT student_pid, id_job, CONCAT('group', FLOOR((student_id - 1) / 4) + 1))
FROM   tbl_students s 
JOIN   r_job_invitations j ON j.email = s.student_email
```

Comment: What if the `student_id` has gaps?

Comment: I dont understand what do you mean by "gaps" the student_id's are like 100 next row 102 next row 109, etc....

Answer (score 1):

I think your code giving you more student then you are looking for. in your code in first loop its running for number of groups time then for each group in next for loop its running for all students in each group.

```
 $limit = (int)($totalIndividuals/$groups);
  for($j =0; $j<$groups;)
  {
    for($i =0; $i<$totalIndividuals; $i++)
    {

     if($i % $limit == 0)
              $j++;
      $GroupsQuery = $conn->query("INSERT INTO r_test_group (student_id,job_id,group_name) values ('".$studentResults['student_pid']."', '".$jobID."','Group'".$j." )");
  }
}
```